# moderator privilege abuse

Tags: support

I have a question about my Computer Science Stack Exchange post: [Deep DFS traverse on graph](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/deep-dfs-traverse-on-graph)

The moderator D.W. abuses his power to lock my account for 7 days and removed all my points. The only question I asked here is perfectly on topic and meets all guidelines. Please resolve this issue.

Answer (score 10):

Here are some options that are available to you, if you wish to dispute a ♦-moderator's actions:

- [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/160917)

The following overview might be helpful:  [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125268/160917)

Comment: I am expecting a formal apology from you. Assuming you still have self-consciousness. Please use the pm system.

Comment: @Kaa1el 1) As Gilles explains to you at length above, there is nothing to apologize for. You *are not owed* an apology; if anything, you should apologize for wasting everybody's time by posting in violation with site rules, and opening this thread. That assumes that you'd read and accept the rules, of course. 2) There is no PM system.

Answer (score 10):

Your account was suspended for 7 days for a reason which was explained (in considerable detail!) in the suspension message. D.W. issued the suspension for perfectly legitimate reasons and in full agreement with the moderation team. There is no abuse of power.

Your account has only one *non-deleted* question. You were suspended because you would not stop posting it again. And again. After being told not to do so.

Your reputation points were not removed. Your reputation appears as 1 while you are suspended but this stopped when the suspension ended as you can see by looking at your account.

For your information, your question currently has 4 close votes as “unclear what you're asking” by community members. A 5th vote would close the question. **You** are the one who can resolve this issue, by **editing** your question to clarify it. As the comments explain, your question needs to be comprehensible on its own. You start with “the above problem”… that's no good: you need to explain the problem. We can't read your mind and you can't expect all the people who read your question to visit the link you gave and figure out what part exactly you are looking at. Please read — and follow — our [guidelines on asking questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43487/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-moderator-privilege-abuse).